# Generalisation of Equilateral Triangle in curved space

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, polygons

It is known that in flat Euclidean Space the internal angles of a triangle sum to $180^{\circ}$ but if we draw a similar triangle in curved space then the sum of interior angles will be more or less depending on whether the curvature is positive or negative, respectively.

Is it possible to construct a geometric figure in curved space such that in the large $N$ limit, where $N$ is the number of sides of the polygon, we have the following two conditions :

1. The angle between *any* two sides is same i.e. $\Delta \theta_{ij}\ \forall\ i,j$ representing two different sides of polygon.
2. The distance between *any* two (and not mere adjacent) vertices remains same?

I don't know how one would proceed to solve the problem or what kind of mathematical language would be used here or if this is a solvable problem.

Any insights would be much appreciated.

Comment: It is possible to construct an equilateral triangle on the surface of a sphere with three right-angles at the corners.

Comment: There is a straightforward generalization of regular polygons to the sphere and hyperbolic plane (as well as spaces locally equivalent to them), but  a more general surface won't be (locally) symmetric enough for the definition to make sense.

Comment: @MarkBennet I agree with your point and that's what I note in my question. Here, I am specifically interested in the large $N$ limit.

Comment: @Kajelad So can you please break it down for a non-mathematician like me? Does that mean such a geometric construction is not possible?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily mean the construction is not possible. It just means that the notion of a "regular polygon" won't easily generalize outside of spaces of constant curvature. As for what you have written, what do you mean by condition 2? For a sufficiently large number of vertices, the distance between *all* pairs cannot be the same (consider the Euclidean plane, for instance: any polygon with $>3$ vertices will not satisfy condition $2$).

Comment: @Kajelad That is exactly what I want to know. As you say, in Euclidean plane $N \gt 3$ will not satisfy condition 2 but since we have curved space can it be possible to have condition 2 satisfied? My motivation to take curved plane is exactly this thing.